# How to pass value to constructor from unity inspector

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, constructor

I have a base abstract `Character` class I created (it extends `MonoBehaviour`) which contains some data, one of which is `maxHealth`. I don't want the `maxHealth` to be changed and so I made it `readonly` and use a property to change it (`public float MaxHealth { get; }`).

I want different characters to have different max hp values so I tried to use a constructor and pass in the max health there but I can't pass a value to the constructor from the unity inspector.

Does anyone have any idea how to pass a value to a constructor from the Unity inspector or any other way to achieve what I'm trying to do (make readonly hp values for different characters and to be able to edit them from just the unity inspector).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MonoBehaviour instances are created using `AddComponent`, not by using `new()`.  Because you are not creating the instance using the `new` keyword, there is no constructor to access.

If you want a variable that can be set from the inspector, but not public, use `[SerializeField]` on a private/protected field.

```
[SerializeField]
private float maxHealth;
public float MaxHealth => maxHealth; // Allow others to use this value, but not change it
```

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for the help. Just tried it out and it worked!